# How to get specific record from model in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to get record from table in YII framework, don't know why it is not working.

```
public function actionGetStarted($id) {
    $curUser = new Customer;
    $curUser->findByPk($id);
    if (!$curUser)
        throw new CHttpException(403, 'Customer Does\'t exists');
    $getStarted = AppContent::model()->findAll();
    $this->render('getStarted', array('getStarted' => $getStarted));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is not according to Yii.

```
public function actionGetStarted($id) {
    $curUser = new Customer;
    $user=$curUser::model()->findByPk($id);
     e($curUser->attributes);// check this line.Also it seems incorrect
     if (empty($user))
        throw new CHttpException(403, 'Customer Does\'t exists');
     // saving current customer to session
     $getStarted = AppContent::model()->findAll();
     $this->render('getStarted', array('getStarted' => $getStarted));
```

}